# Cholesky decomposition problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $$S=S^{T}$$ be a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix with Cholesky decomposition $S=LDL^{T}$. Prove or disprove the following statement:
The product of the diagonal elements of $D$ equals to the product of the eigenvalues of $S$.